# Getting a MD5 signature for the Google API

Tags: android, google-maps, md5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android:Google Maps API Key Signup : MD5 certification key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696288/androidgoogle-maps-api-key-signup-md5-certification-key)

I'm tryng to use the Google API to display a map in an application. So far, the result I have got is an empty map.

I'm sure that the problem comes from my md5 key. I tryied to get the MD5 signature of my `debug.keystore` file using the keytool command as shown in the "Hello-mapview" tutorial but without success. I then determined the MD5 signature using the Windows application "WinMD5". The maps remains unfortunately blank...

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps [here](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#getdebugfingerprint) to find your MD5 fingerprint.  Then enter the fingerprint [here](http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html) to obtain your API key.  The API key is what you need to put in your layout file which is explained in the "Hello, MapView" tutorial.