# Android:Google Maps API Key Signup : MD5 certification key

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

how to get MD5 fingerprint key .

I am using this command :

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin>keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\IBM\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android    `
```

but unable to get MD5 key, but I am getting Certificate fingerprint (SHA1) key

```
androiddebugkey, Jan 16, 2012, PrivateKeyEntry,Certificate fingerprint (SHA1):A4:9E:8F:FA:1A:B2:A0:79:3D:D3:95:41:82:3B:F6:DA:78:40:DD:DE
```

I want **MD5 certification key**.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Google has now deprecated this service for Android Applications.

Comment: @Cool Jatt any document proof for the same

Comment: @BlackDevil: Please check this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview

Comment: @BlackDevil: Can you help me with this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216205/google-map-android-api-v2-sample-code-not-working

Comment: Sry @CoolJatt I am somewhat stuck to somewhat same issue. Still check out what can I do.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin>keytool.exe -V -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\IBM\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```

Consider your `jdk-bin path` in the `first path` place and your `home user directory` in the `second path`. For `windows 7` it is like`C:\Users\username\.android\debug.keystore`

Use the above command you will get all the keys.

[The google API key is here](http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html).

Answer (score 8):

for windows

step1: start --> run-->

type

C:\Documents and Settings\ashish\.android

***hear you should be pass your current user***
and find debug.keystore

[image: description]

now get the path of debug.keystore

```
C:\Documents and Settings\ashish\.android\debug.keystore
```

now  the command for getting MD5

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore <path_to_debug_keystore>.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

so now we pass the path of dedug.keystore

the full command is

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\ashish\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```

step 2: start--> run-->

type cmd and change directory to **android sdk's platform-tools** and past the following command
[image]
press enter

[image]

now  you are getting MD5 now how to use it.....
now Go to https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup

[image]

after that press button It will give you map api

Answer (score 7):

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android refer this link.

Use JDK version 1.6 instead of 1.7 because 1.7 generates the fingerprint with SHA1 by default.

Comment: thanks @richa but i dint got it. This link is giving me same output.

Comment: I want MD5 certificate not SHA1 Certificate fingerprint. please if any other solutions guide me. thanks a lot.

Comment: write "-v" at the end it will give you both SHA1 and MD5 fingerprint

Comment: @KKD -- I am getting now. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

For window You can use like this.

1.Go to start then run open cmd  then type

C:\Documents and Settings\NEETIKA.android\debug.keystore

Now use the following command for getting the MD5 fingerprint.

keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android

You will get the finger print after that

To find google API key : use this link -- http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html

Answer (score 3):

For developing google maps application in android,the first step is to get Google APIs(containing maps.jar).
If its not available in your Eclipse IDE,you can download it in eclipse by going to windows>Android sdk manager>...then select the required Google API.
Create a new AVD with the target as google APIs this is where you run the google maps application.

To get MD5 fingerprint run the following command in cmd

keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore “C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.android\debug.keystore” -storepass android -keypass android

before executing this command,
1.change the path of cmd to keytool.exe's location which is generally inside program files>java>bin
2.inside double quotes enter the path to your android keystore,which can be found in eclipse..windows>preferences>android>build

while tring this the issues that i faced were
1.keytool error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Usage error, and is not a legal command----because of unwanted spaces
2.tried to insert -v command for verbose

After getting MD5,go to the following link http://code.google. com/android/maps-api-signup.html and sign in with your google account.to obtain the key which you can use in your application.

Answer (score 3):

signup link for android map api key 'https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup' is not working.

showing 'Could not connect to remote server' in iframe above the fotter of the page.did any one worked on it recently?

Comment: I got key at [link](
http://t3g-garrett.appspot.com/code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html)

Answer (score 2):

As much I know, the above which you got is the key, now u need to register it at this [link](http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html).

Comment: I have to signup in that link. but i need MD5 keys. Now I am getting that by typing `-V ` b4 `-list` to my command i ll get all keys. Thank you

Comment: Good. So you got a success. :)

Answer (score 2):

The above answers show how to obtain the md5 key but newer versions of the jdk generate more keys and display the SHA1 as default. To obtain the md5 key for 1.7 and later:

1   go to command line
2   go to dir of keystore   C:\Users\Gideon.android
3   enter this command  keytool -v -list -keystore "C:\Users\Gideon.android\debug.keystore" android

4   look for the code with MD5:
    mine was:

Answer (score 1):

```
use **-V** in cmd prompt........:)
```

Answer (score 0):

For windows

1.Locate your debug.keystore file
 "C:\Users\bhushan.android\debug.keystore"

2.Locate keytool.exe in Java\bin folder

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin>keytool -v -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore
 C:\Users\bshirsath\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
Alias name: androiddebugkey
Creation date: Mar 8, 2012
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Issuer: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Serial number: 1f5b8c95
Valid from: Thu Mar 08 17:51:52 IST 2012 until: Sat Mar 01 17:51:52 IST 2042
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  6E:E7:47:2E:A7:07:8A:42:77:89:A8:83:C7:A6:53:87
         SHA1: 1D:99:2B:0E:D3:2F:DE:12:92:CE:86:EE:5A:D2:99:80:28:F7:B6:22
         SHA256: 30:0B:FC:40:7F:57:9F:51:FF:60:94:B9:CE:27:C1:7A:9D:EF:F7:14:C8:
36:B0:E8:F4:11:13:23:B1:67:17:08
         Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
         Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: DF 53 60 E5 59 3A 8C 07   EA E1 A2 3F 00 57 45 DD  .S`.Y:.....?.WE.
0010: DF 29 08 BA                                        .)..
]
]
```

4.Get a key for the Google Maps Android API v1:
 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/maps-api-signup

5.To register for a Google Maps Android API v1 Key, follow these steps:

-->If you don't have a Google account, use the link on the page to set one up.

-->Paste the MD5 key

-->Click "Generate API Key"

Answer (score -1):

You miss the -v parameter in the command line (for verbose i assume). without the -v only give you the SHA1 check-sum. with the -v give you all of them: MD5, SHA1, SHA256 and all info about the certificate.