# android google map api key obtaining?

Tags: android

I had google map apikey for a project now I want apikey for another project and this projects keystore is in a different place. My first cmd:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin\keytool.exe" -v -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\salih\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```

it is working but my for my new project I use this command and I had eror.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin\keytool.exe" -v -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\salih\workspace\kimlimkey.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```

error;

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was
incorrect
java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:772)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:5
5)
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1214)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doCommands(KeyTool.java:789)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(KeyTool.java:340)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(KeyTool.java:333)
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed

        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:770)
        ... 5 more
```

I do something illegal? or I am mistake? is there any other way to get another md5 fingerprint?

Comment: duplicate question of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696288/androidgoogle-maps-api-key-signup-md5-certification-key